# Error : Install mysql by package .deb from oracle

Tags: mysql

```
root@ubuntu:/home/brosl/Downloads# dpkg -i mysql-common_8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb

Message: (Reading database ... 315468 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack mysql-common_8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking mysql-common (8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04) over (8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04) ...
Setting up mysql-common (8.0.16-2ubuntu18.04) ...
update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist
dpkg: error processing package mysql-common (--install):
 installed mysql-common package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 2
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-common
```

Answer (score 0):

The fix for

> update-alternatives: error: alternative path /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback doesn't exist

could be

```
sudo cp /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf.fallback
```

Mind though that this error occurs when you already have a mysql installed and this is kind of an emergency stop: it would kill your current installation.

It is expected you first -purge- the old version. And if you want to keep the database from that installation you also need to make a dump of your current database.